# Error: Error creating contact table: No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

This is code I'm following a tutorial but I keep getting an error. I'm a beginner but I'm not really sure "why" I'm getting this error.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('dbaddress', 'username', 'password');  
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE contact (  
      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
      contacttext TEXT,  
      contactdate DATE NOT NULL  
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8';

if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {  
  $output = 'Error creating contact table: ' . mysqli_error($link);  
  include 'output.html.php';  
  exit();  
}  

$output = 'Contact table successfully created.';  
include 'output.html.php';
?>
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE dbaddress.contact` ...

Comment: The full address, or is there a variable created from the first part of the code?

Comment: just DATABASE_NAME DOT TABLE_NAME there are other ways, but i'm use to dealing with multi db systems so being real clear on what db you are using  is my default practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have three option to solve this error.

1. First, you can specify the database name in the arguments of the `mysqli_connect` function:

   `$link = mysqli_connect('dbaddress', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');`
2. Second, you can manually select the required database. Insert following line after `mysqli_connect` line:

   `mysqli_select_db($link, 'dbname');`
3. Or, you can specify the database name in SQL statement after `CREATE TABLE`:

   `CREATE TABLE dbname.contact`

I recommend you the first solution, that is the easiest way.

Comment: The first solution worked. Thank you. Sorry if it was a stupid question, very new to all this.

Comment: You are welcome. Do not worry, I asked similar 'stupid' questions when I started to learn these things.

Answer (score 2):

`$link = mysqli_connect('dbaddress', 'username', 'password');` 
         `mysqli_select_db($link, 'dbname');`

You forgot to select database.

Comment: Params for mysqli_select_db are backwards

Comment: Always get confused with them. Edited the post.